# No such file or directory - bin error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am trying to run a application through my tcl script.

Typically I would go to the directory `cd /OpenTimer/` and then type `./bin/ot-shell` to run the application.

In my script the line that executes this command is:

```
set time_elapsed_in_us [time {exec /OpenTimer/bin/ot-shell < $OutputDirectory/$DesignName.conf >& $OutputDirectory/$DesignName.results} 1]
puts "time_elapsed_in_us is $time_elapsed_in_us"
```

And I am getting this:

```
error
couldn't execute "/OpenTimer/bin/ot-shell/": no such file or directory
    while executing
```

Also `ot-shell` is a shared library.

Comment: Does `/OpenTimer/bin/ot-shell/` exist?

Comment: It exists in the sense that you have to first cd into OpenTimer and then execute ./bin/ot-shell since ot-shell isn't a directory   (bash: cd: ot-shell: Not a directory)